# Kprobe bpf_map_delete_elem called from userland

Tags: linux, kernel, ebpf

I'm working on monitoring changes to eBPF Maps from both userland and the kernel. I followed the repo (https://github.com/CrowdStrike/bpfmon-example) and modified the map type to LRU HASH Map, with added support for `bpf_map_delete_elem`.

For handling `bpf_map_update_elem`, I can use kprobes such as `bpf_map_update_value.isra.0` for userland and `htab_lru_map_update_elem` for the kernel. However, I'm encountering difficulties in finding a corresponding kprobes for monitoring `bpf_map_delete_elem`. While I've identified `htab_lru_map_delete_elem` for kernel space, I'm unable to locate an equivalent for userland, akin to `bpf_map_delete_value.isra.0`. I've tried the kprobes listed by bpftrace related to map element deletion, but none of them get triggered when I call `bpf_map_delete_elem` in userland.

Is there a kprobe available for monitoring `bpf_map_delete_elem` called from userland (Linux kernel version: 5.15)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to the [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/kernel/bpf/syscall.c), both userland and kernel space syscall for map element deletion end up calling the same function `map->ops->map_delete_elem`, specifically `htab_lru_map_delete_elem`. However, userland syscall executes `bpf_disable_instrumentation()` before calling `map->ops->map_delete_elem` to prevent deadlock.

To capture syscalls from userland, we typically kprobe a higher-level function, such as `bpf_map_update_value.isra.0` for map update. Unfortunately, no such kprobe function exists for map element deletion. Alternatively, we can leverage the tracepoint `__sys_enter_bpf` which triggers for all BPF operations from userland. By filtering these operations through their arguments, we can identify map element deletion operations.

Answer (score 1):

**/!\ See [MJTony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78055726/6884590). This answer is missing `bpf_disable_instrumentation`.**

---

> For handling `bpf_map_update_elem`, I can use kprobes such as `bpf_map_update_value.isra.0` for userland and `htab_lru_map_update_elem` for the kernel.

Note that for userland, `bpf_map_update_elem` ends up calling `htab_lru_map_update_elem` as well so if you trace both, I'd expect you to intercept the same map update twice.

The same seems to apply to map delete operation, for which **tracing `htab_lru_map_delete_elem` should be enough to see map deletes from both userland and BPF programs**.

Comment: In reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782101/what-is-the-detailed-process-of-bps-api-map-helpers-like-bpf-map-update-elem), the syscalls used for `bpf_map_update_elem` differ between userland and kernel space. I've verified that `htab_lru_map_update_elem` does not capture userland calls. This holds true for map deletion as well.

Comment: Weird. That doesn't match my read of the source code. Both [userland](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/kernel/bpf/syscall.c#L1205) and the [helper](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/kernel/bpf/helpers.c#L66) seem to call `map->ops->map_delete_elem` which is `htab_lru_map_delete_elem` for LRU maps.

Comment: Indeed, both userland and kernel space calls utilize the same function `map->ops->map_delete_elem`. I just notice that the syscall from userland executes `bpf_disable_instrumentation()` just before calling `map->ops->map_delete_elem` to prevent deadlocks. This may explain why `htab_lru_map_delete_elem` isn't triggered by map elem deletion from userland.

Comment: @MJTony Oh, nice catch! I think you should post an answer to explain; I'd upvote it. Otherwise I'll update mine.